# How to open a Qt project from github

Tags: c++, qt

I  downloaded this project from github: https://github.com/Zarkus13/BomberMan-CPP.git
I cant open this in Qt. How can I do that?

Comment: It' has a `.pro` file. Qt-Creator should use that.

Comment: ***I cant open this in Qt*** Why can't you? Does it have some type of error code?

Comment: I can say one thing about this project. The person that published it did not 
remove the compiled output or ignore it with a .gitignore file. Not sure if it was meant to be used by anyone other than the person developing.

Comment: added a point; I see no .pro either.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded it, and while Qt complains about an older version of Qt, the **.pro** file opens fine.

Perhaps you're trying to open the directory. You have to open the file. I did it this way:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:Zarkus13/BomberMan-CPP.git
Cloning into 'BomberMan-CPP'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 135, done.
remote: Total 135 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 135
Receiving objects: 100% (135/135), 3.71 MiB | 5.94 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (17/17), done.
$ cd BomberMan-CPP/
$ open BomberMan.pro
```